# Openshift Pods Failed To Run After Java Version Upgrade as Base Image

Tags: java, docker, openshift

I want to upgrade some spring boot service from java-8 to java-11 (11.0.1 version).

I upgraded the project locally, compile and run it - succeeded.
I created a new docker image (with java-11 as base image) for the project and run it over a server, the container run successfully, and showed logs.

But, when I changed the image of the deployment on openshift, the pod starts as everything is ok (blue), but then crashes repeatedly (stuck in crash loop and restart himself) and doesn’t show any logs.

The used base image :   openjdk:11.0.1-jre-slim-sid

Does anyone have any idea what could cause this problem or how can I see logs and investigate this issue?

Comment: Memory can cause on this error. Is there any error about OOM Killed? Or can you monitor memory when it is running?

Comment: In addition, check openshift's events